# OpenCV: Draw major axis of contour

Tags: opencv, draw, axis, contour

I am currently working on cell contour detection with OpenCV. So far, I have been able to detect the cell contours and I want to find and draw the longest axis parallel to the y-axis of the contour.

What I did was create a bounding rectangle from the contour which finds the center and the height and width and use this information to draw the axes. As it turns out, the major axis does not necessarily run through the center, so at times it peeks over the cell contour.

My line of approach is to split the contour into a semi-circle along the y-axis, aquire the perpendicular distance from each contour point to the y-axis and then select the longest on each side, but I suppose this is computationally expensive.

Is there an easy way to find the longest axes of a contour (not a bounding rectangle), that are parallel to the x- or y- coordinate axis?

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNVSK.jpg) - My cell contour is in thin black, major and minor axes are in red, and the blue "axes" are what I want to find.

Comment: I think that you need to use pca:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731368/opencv-pca-application-error-in-image-proc/21735828#21735828

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for the suggestion. I need to clarify: the axes I am looking need to be parallel to the x- and y- coordinate axes. I should probably write this more clearly. Also, PCA does not necessarily give me the length of the axis up to the contour, as far as I know?

Comment: If I undestand the idea now, the lineIterator should be useful for you.  ( See  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator )  You just need pass two points as parameters, and find first nonzero value from the end.

Comment: can you draw and link (uploaded on image hosting webspace) an image (or multiple images) showing what kind of axis you mean?

Comment: Micka, I added an image. Andrey, if I understand it correctly I could use this to scan the image along rows (resp. columns) using the contours corresponding two points on the same row (column)? I'll try to implement that and see how well it does.

Comment: Just as a late follow-up: I decided to use the bounding rectangle in the end, as the computation involved was slowing the program down and the answers weren't significantly different from the bounding rectangle.